# I need to create a Logic that creates a new loop per item based on the Input Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I need to create a logic of nested for, that the number of the loops is based in the input Array Lenght.

This array could have N values, the name of the array is penalities and I need to make my logic based on that interactions.

If the input array length N is 3,  like penalities array [1, 2, 3]

My code needs to result

```
for (let x = 1; x <= 2; x += 0.1) {
   for (let y = 1; y <= 2; y += 0.1) {
      for (let z = 1; z <= 2; z += 0.1) {
         const penalities = [x, y, z];
         myFunction(penalities);
      }
   }
}
enter code here
```

If the input array length N is 4,  like penalities array= [1, 2, 3, 4]

My code needs to result

```
for (let x = 1; x <= 2; x += 0.1) {
   for (let y = 1; y <= 2; y += 0.1) {
      for (let z = 1; z <= 2; z += 0.1) {
          for (let k = 1; k <= 2; k += 0.1) {
            const penalities = [x, y, z, k];
             myFunction(penalities);
          }
      }
   }
}
```

How can I make this iteration logic generic to receive any quantity inside the array, without having to create N nested for.

Comment: why sometimes `value` or `array.length - 1` what do you do with the items of the array? do you have an example with innner logic?

Comment: Do you need access to `i`, `j` and `k` while inside loop `l`?

Comment: You probably don't need nested `for`s, that's why people are asking. You might be able to use a single loop that goes over the array N times, for instance.

Comment: Sketch of a recursive approach… `function f(i, arr) { for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) { if (i) { f(i - 1, arr); } else { ... } } }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach and take an indices array for the values of each loop.

```js
function iterate(array, cb) {
    function iter(index) {
        for (let i = 0, l = array[index]; i < l; i++) {
            indices[index] = i;
            if (index + 1 === array.length) cb(indices);
            else iter(index + 1);
        }
    }
    const indices = [];
    iter(0);
}

iterate([3, 2, 2, 4], indices => console.log(...indices));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the messy question, but that is the exact logic that I need.
Thanks.

Comment: Played around with the function for a bit and have to say it is really nice, up voted your answer. @OP your question was horrible, no hard feelings. Happy coding.